# Mistake in proof of sum of divisors function $\sigma(n)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, summation

The proof derives the correct result, but I cannot see how the first equality is correct.

To begin we use the formula $\sigma(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}d$

This is the first step in the proof:

$$\sum_{1\leq n\leq x}\sigma(n)=\sum_{1\leq n\leq x}\sum_{d\mid n}n/d$$

Surely this first step is a simple substitution of our formula

Shouldn't it be $$\sum_{1\leq n\leq x}\sigma(n)=\sum_{1\leq n\leq x}\sum_{d\mid n}d$$

If not, why do we choose substitute in this way to sum over $n/d$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you take divisors $d$ of $n$, $\frac{n}{d}$ runs through the divisors in reverse order, so the sums are the same.

For instance for $n=10$, the $d$ values are $1, 2, 5, 10$; and the corresponding $\frac{n}{d}$ values are $\frac{10}{1}, \frac{10}{2}, \frac{10}{5}, \frac{10}{10}$, or simply $10, 5, 2, 1$.

Answer (score 2):

$d\mapsto\dfrac nd\,$ is a permutation of the set of divisors of $n$, so the sums are equal.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the confusion.  When looking at number theory calculations you have to think through each step and avoid the simple algebraic simplifications that one usually applies when manipulating sums.  Otherwise you see steps that may not at first make sense.  So in affect you read these expressions slowly.  Hope this helps.